# Awesome wm Unagi transparency for bars

Tags: lua, awesome-wm

[Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) is a window manager that lets you setup the environment through a programming language(Lua) .I installed [Unagi](http://unagi.mini-dweeb.org/)(compositing window manager) and I can make firefox transparent .For example this `awful.rules`:

```
{rule = {class = "Firefox"}, 
 properties = {opacity = 0.8} }
```

How would you make the `awful.wibox` transparent by setting up the rules? or is there a different way of making the `awful.wibox` transparent?

```
wmbar = awful.wibox({ position = "right", screen = 1 })
wmbar.widgets = { 
    widget1,
    widget2,
    layout = awful.widget.layout.vertical.flex }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rules of awesome's window matching (for setting opacity) relies on window properties, which you can see using `xprop`.
wibox, including promptbox, layoutbox, taglist and tasklist renders on panel window. You can set opacity of any window on x-server (including awesome panel) independently of your window manager using `transset-df` (`pacman -S transset-df` for arch), for example. But you can't change opacity of only fragment of external window, and awesome doesn't support transparency by itself - it fully relies on underlying composite managers.